# Load data from MySQL into JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have two `MySQL` tables as image below

**movie**
[image]

**movie_title**

[image]

```
         JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.setBounds(125, 15, 190, 20);
         try {   
            DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
            Connection connect=db.getConnection();
            String sql="Select title FROM movie_title";
            PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("title");
            combo.addItem(name);            
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
         combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        JComboBox comboBox=(JComboBox) event.getSource();
         Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
         displayDay(selected);
    }

    private void displayDay(Object selected) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {  
                combo1.removeAllItems();
                DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
                Connection connect=db.getConnection();
                String sql="Select movie_day FROM movie WHERE movie_title = ?";
                PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setObject(1, selected);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                String day = rs.getString("movie_day");
                combo1.addItem(day);   
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }

    }
        });
```

I have implemented `ActionListener` in `comboBox`. When user select movie Marvel's Captain America, it will get the `movie_day` item from movie and load into combo1. **Is there a way I can make the combo1 display the movie_day which is Sunday, 28 Apr 2016 one time only instead of two ?**

**Edit**

```
private void displayDay(Object selected) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {  
                combo1.removeAllItems();
                DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
                Connection connect=db.getConnection();
                String sql="Select movie_day FROM movie WHERE movie_title = ?";
                PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setObject(1, selected);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                String day = rs.getString("movie_day");
                DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)combo1.getModel();                
                if (model.getIndexOf(day) == -1)
                {
                    combo1.addItem(day);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make the combo1 display the movie_day which is Sunday, 28 Apr 2016 one time only instead of two ?

Before adding the date to the combo box you need to check if the date already exists.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)comboBox.getModel();

if (model.getIndexOf(theDate) == -1)
{
    comboBox.addItem( theDate );
}
```

You could also change the SQL statement to only get "unique" dates, but I don't know SQL well enough to give you the actual syntax. Maybe this [SQL Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) will help, otherwise you need to find a better tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand why need to add the date to combo box. I want to add the movie_day in combo1 only

Comment: Between, DefaultComboBoxModel cannot resolve as a type

Comment: @JohnJoe, 1) I gave you example code. Use your variable names. 2) Use the proper import for the class. This is basic Java. You should be able to solve compile problems. Look up the API for the class in question if you don't know how to use it.